# Ada - Type out a string using S'length

Tags: string, ada

The problem is simple and can be solved by a simple Get_Line, but the problem suggests otherwise.

A subprogram has to be created. The subprogram should only have one parameter (which is the string) and return length of the string (as an integer) of course. To get the length of a string you could do S'Length and you have to use the length of the string when you type out in your main program.

For instance:

Type a string containing 3 letters: **Wow**

You typed the string: Wow

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure String_Program is

    function String_Length (S : in String) return Integer is
        Res : Integer;

    begin
        Res := S'Length;
        return Res;

    end String_Length;
     
    S : String (1 .. 3);

begin
    Put("Type a string containing 3 letters: ");
    Get(S);
    Put("You typed the string: ");
    Put(String_Length(S), Width => 1); 

end String_Program;
```

I've done as instructed but my program types out the actual number corresponding the amount of characters there are in the string. So when I type "Hey" it will type out "3". And I know why it is like that because I'm returning the actual length of the string as an integer. How do I type the actual string out and not the number? After all I'm returning an integer so it will be tough.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "type the actual string out" in the context of your overall question.  At face value, I would just say Put(S) as that prints the string.  Can you elaborate with an example of what you want to see in the output given a specific input?

Comment: I typed an example of how it should look (look above the code) If you type a string containing 3 letters like “Hey” it should type out “Hey”. But I don’t know how to solve it following the given conditions (that I stated in my question). The only tip that I got was that the whole length of a string can be written as S’Length

Comment: Create a subroutine that receives a string via the parameter list and
returns the length of the string (as an integer).

The subroutine may only have one parameter.

 You can get the length of a string S by typing S'Length.

NOTE! When printing the string in the main program, use
the length of this subprogram.

Comment: As you may have gathered from previous answers, `String_Length` does not need to create an intermediate variable. It can simply `return S'Length;`

Comment: @leun Then use Put(S); and that should print the string Wow in yuor case.

Comment: Right, but it will still not work because it'll still return an integer to my main program. That's my concern right here

Comment: @Jere That's what I've done in my program shown as above but it only prints out the actual length of the string in numbers. If a string contains 2 letters it will type out the number 2.

Comment: You have not used `Put(S)` but rather `Put(String_Length(S))`, which does what you've told it to and printed the length of the string.

Comment: Yes but if I do Put(S) I could might aswell fully disregard my subprogram as my subprogram won't do anything. The ask is to use S'Length to type the word out.

Comment: @leun Do you want to put out the string one character at a time in a loop? Then you can use `String_Length`..

Comment: Yes, but how would that loop look like. I assume it would look something like 

For I in 1 .. S loop      

Put(S +1)
end loop;

Comment: More like 'for I in 1 .. String_Length (S) loop Put (S (I)); end loop;'.

Comment: Have you been introduced to declare blocks yet, as a way of handling unknown length strings?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been introduced to declare blocks yet, as a way of handling unknown length strings?

Because the problem statement

> A subprogram has to be created. The subprogram should only have one parameter (which is the string) and return length of the string (as an integer) of course. To get the length of a string you could do S'Length and you have to use the length of the string when you type out in your main program.

by not mentioning a specific string length, is screaming loud and clear for a declare block in the main program...

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure String_Program is

    function String_Length (S : in String) return Integer is 
    begin
       return S'Length;
    end String_Length;

begin

    Put("Type a string : ");
    declare
       S : String := Get_Line;
    begin   
       Put( "Your string : " & S & " has ");
       Put( String_Length(S), Width => 1); 
       Put_Line(" characters");
    end;

end String_Program;
```

However, remember your professor undoubtedly watches Stack Overflow, so you can't simply use this program as it is.

Comment: Just by looking at this program it seems that the main program types out the amount of characters in a string. For instance "Heydd" would give the value 5 and the main program would type out "5". That's not what I'm looking for.

But I might be wrong, correct me if I am

Comment: It prints both the string and its length. Question asks you to USE the length function but doesn't tell you HOW to use it. I have no idea what you're looking for, this answer is just my understanding of the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure String_Program is

   function String_Length (S : in String) return Natural is
   begin
      return S'Length;
   end String_Length;

   S : String (1 .. 3);
begin
   Put ("Type a string containing 3 letters: ");
   Get (S);
   Put ("You typed the string: ");

   -- Put string S to standard output one character at a time
   -- using String_Length.
   for Offset in 0 .. String_Length (S) - 1 loop
      Put (S (S'First + Offset));
   end loop;
   New_Line;

end String_Program;
```

Comment: The `Put` procedure in `Ada.Text_IO` is overloaded. It can put a `String` as well as a `Character`.